# Reset password on Windows Mobile

Tags: exchange-2003, password, windows-mobile

I have users using Windows Mobile 6 phones synchronising via Exchange ActiveSync with Exchange 2003.

We're planning to make it mandatory for them to have a PIN on the phones, but what do we do if they forget it?  Is there a way to reset the password from the server end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using Exchange 2007 a user can [reset the password](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2007/05/30/439568.aspx) using the OWA/web interface. It's a bit tricky because it's a generated string of numbers to confirm the "recover password" option available on the Windows Mobile's password screen in the "menu" menu.

With an older version of Exchange this is sadly not supported but you can do a factory reset / remote wipe of the device and configure it again. As all data should be in Exchange (contacts, calendar and so on), this shouldn't be a problem in a controlled environment - it's just like re-imaging a computer.

[Mobile device support difference between Exchange 2003 and 2007](http://www.petri.co.il/differences_exchange2003_exchange2007_mobile_features.htm)

If you're using [System Center Mobile Device Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/en-us/business/solutions/enterprise/mobile-device-manager.mspx) there's an [addon](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53799354-e949-47e6-8f2d-8395fc213d60&displaylang=en) that will enable a user to reset their windows mobile 6.1+ device passwords.

Comment: That link is to Exchange 2007, not 2003. That screen isn't there in 2003, but thanks, at least I now know what my problem is.

Comment: Ah, yeah - I missed that. This is sadly a new feature of 2007 :(